# Implementing Sticky Header with FirestorePagingAdapter in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, stickyrecycleview

I tried to implement a custom sticky header with [edubarr/header-decor](https://github.com/edubarr/header-decor) with [firestore paging adapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore). i have created custom adapter by extending FirestorePagingAdapter to implement the custom sticky header. since Firestore paging adapter refreshing multiple times dynamically for every scrolling application is hanging. If anybody having sample for sticky-header implementation with FirestorePagingAdapter without hanging the application.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sample needed for sticky-header implementation with FirestorePagingAdapter without hanging the application.